# Is there a way to use plink with rsync on Windows?

Tags: ssh, rsync, plink

I use rsync to sync files between a local directory and a remote host. I also use plink to automate my SSH passphase entry.

What I can't figure out is how to use rsync with plink. This is what I think the syntax should be:

```
rsync -args --rsh="plink user@remote" local_dir/ :/remote_dir
```

But I get "Access Denied" messages. Is there a way to do this? Is it simple?

**Edited** to reflect what I think the syntax should look like. I had it very wrong before.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an incompatibility in stdin/stdout redirection between cygwin and native Win32 programs.

Someone has managed to make a wrapper that solves the problem:

http://diario.beerensalat.info/2009/08/18/new_cygnative_version_1_2_for_rsync_plink.html

The usage would be something like:

```
rsync -args -e="cygnative plink" local_dir/ user@remote:/remote_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete Batch-file to solve the problem:

```
rem This is file: copy_win_inifiles_to_linux_via_rsync_with_pagent.bat

rem This is what I want:
rem
rem Windows with Putty+Pagent -> rsync -> Linux
rem 
rem pagent.exe is already loaded with my ssh-key
rem This ssh-key shall make the authentication to the remote rsyncd/Linux
rem
rem Environment for this Batch-file:
rem
rem plink.exe for Windows, derived from cygwin
rem download here:
rem    http://it-em.net/joomla/downloads/rsync.zip
rem    with german dokumentation in http://it-em.net/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=49&Itemid=54cms/front_content.php
rem cygnative.exe is needed from plink.exe (putty-suite) 
rem so that plink.exe works together wird rsync.exe
rem download cygnative here:
rem     http://diario.beerensalat.info/2009/08/18/new_cygnative_version_1_2_for_rsync_plink.html
rem
rem Filetree looks like this:
rem + copy_win_inifiles_to_linux_via_rsync_with_pagent.bat
rem + bin/
rem      + rsync.exe
rem      + cygwin1.dll         # needed from rsync.exe
rem      + cygiconv-2.dll      # needed from rsync.exe
rem      + cyggcc_s-1.dll      # needed from rsync.exe
rem      + cygnative.exe       # standalone-program
rem      + plink.exe           # from putty-suite, standalone-program
rem + ini/                     # Here are the file which shall be transferred
rem      + bla.ini
rem      + foo.ini
rem
rem our current working is the same where this bat-file is

set SRC_DIR=./ini/
set DST_USER=yourusername
set DST_SERVER=your-linux-server.somewhere.com
set DST_PORT=22
set DST_DIR=/home/yourusername/what/ever/ini

bin\rsync.exe -v -d --delete -e="./bin/cygnative.exe ./bin/plink.exe -P %DST_PORT%" %SRC_DIR% %DST_USER%@%DST_SERVER%:%DST_DIR%
```

Comment: The link to `cygnative.exe` is dead. Here are a couple of alternatives that I managed to find: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/silviuvulcan/7609c438f6ab5e51c8d19890e949565f) and [this zip](http://franklinstrube.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/cygnative1.2.zip). I have used the executable contained in the zip, but I cannot vouch for either source. The original author would appear to have taken down his blog, however his website is [here](http://frank-behrens.de).

Answer (score 0):

I typically do my rsyncs over ssh with something similar to the following:

> rsync -args -e "ssh -i .ssh/my-key"
>   user@hostname:/dir1 /dir2

You could try substituting the appropriate plink or putty command.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working for me. Please see my edits because I originally messed up the syntax of the rsync command.